# Remembering CodeIgniter form_dropdown fields

Tags: validation, forms, codeigniter, select

This works...

```
form_dropdown('location', $location_options, $this->input->post('location'));
```

But when I try and use an array to add extra attributes, it stops working... Why is this?

```
$attributes = array(
    'name' => 'location',
    'id' => 'location'
);

form_dropdown($attributes, $location_options, $this->input->post('location'));
```

The name of the dropdown list is included in the array of attributes so i don't see how this is any different to the first example. Whenever the form is posted posted back, it resets to the start.

Can anyone help me out with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the wrong syntax.

Please have a look at the docu: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

```
form_dropdown('location', $location_options, $this->input->post('location'), "id='location'");
```

Your code should look something like the above. And by the way: if you're using the form_validation library you could use set_value instead of $this->input->post ...

Comment: Ok, looks like wrong syntax... Doesn't explain how you can pass in an array of attributes and still keep the values on a "form_input" field but cant do the same with a "form_dropdown" field without losing the post data.

Comment: You add your attributes as a string as the last argument of form_dropdown().

Comment: Important: for set_value() to work when the form validation library is used, the field ('location' in this example) must be part of the validation rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $attributes = ' id="bar" class="foo" onChange="some_function();"';
    $location_options = array(
       'IN' =>'India',
       'US' =>'America'
    );

 form_dropdown('location', $location_options, $this->input->post('location'),$attributes);
```

**Parameters :**

1. 1st param will assign to name of the field,
2. 2nd will get your options,
3. 3rd is for default value,
4. 4th one is for extra properties to add like javascript function, id, class ...